Symbolic computation of Boolean functions
There are several packages such as SAGEmath, Maple, Mathematica as well as other OS packages which perform Boolean function symbolic arithmetic. Computations in this arithmetic are about performing OR ($\vee$), AND ($\wedge$), XOR ($\oplus$), Compositions $f\circ g$ in the Boolean algebra (and ring) of polynomials in several variables with Boolean $B_0=\{0,1\}$ co-efficients and variables taking values in this Boolean algebra. Unfortunately some of these operations are not scalable as number of variables increase. One of my students even tried developing Python codes to write these operations from scratch but again they fail as degree of terms and number of variables increase. Especially composition seems to be hardest to scale. Can somebody help how this computation can be done?

There is competition even for this, an example is minisat. The problem is hard. The question what they are trying to achive?

Why this question is in the Meta-site?
